# Getting data from Gitolite config file from bash script

Tags: git, gitolite

I have a project where admins are listed in the gitolite.conf.

For example:

@admins = bettina bastian angela robert

Now I want to get @admins inside a post-update hook.

Is there a way of expanding this list?

Answer (score 1):

The management of hooks in Gitolite (especially the latest [Gitolite V3 or 'g3'](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/why.html)) is very simple:

> #### [Customising your Gitolite: hooks](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#hooks)
>
> Gitolite uses the `update` hook for all repos.
>   In addition, it uses the `post-update` hook for the `gitolite-admin` repo.
>
> If you want to add your own hook, it's easy as long as it's not the '`update`' hook. Just add it to `$HOME/.gitolite/hooks/common` and run `gitolite setup`.
>
> **The rest is between you and '`man githooks`'** :-)

So... no. There is no Gitolite native way to reference a Gitolite group, which means your script will have to parse [`$HOME/.gitolite/conf/gitolite.conf'][3] and get the`@admins` users that way.